# Lambda query to reverse order a list by date

Tags: linq, lambda, asp.net-3.5

I have this function that shows a list of messages in reverse order.

```
 protected void setupMessages(IList<Message> Messages)
 {
     List<Message> messages = new List<Message>() ;
     messages.AddRange( Messages.OrderBy(message => message.DateAdded).Reverse());
     MessagesRepeater.DataSource = messages;
     MessagesRepeater.DataBind();
 }
```

I was wondering if there was a way to reverse the order within the lambda query without calling the Reverse Method? Or is calling Reverse() the only way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply want to use the [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) extension method, as opposed to `OrderBy`.

Indeed, this would be a more efficient method, since it only requires one iteration of the collection rather than two.

```
messages.AddRange(Messages.OrderByDescending(message => message.DateAdded));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)

```
messages.AddRange( Messages.OrderByDescending( message => message.DateAdded ) );
```

In fact, you can simplify the whole thing:

```
protected void setupMessages(IList<Message> Messages)
{     
     MessagesRepeater.DataSource = Messages.OrderByDescending( message => message.DateAdded )
                                           .ToList();
     MessagesRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. You are both right, but Noldorin was first.

Thanks for the code, but the reason that I used the intermediate collection was because I got an error saying my data source must implement ICollection or can perform data source paging if AllowPaging is true.

Comment: @NetHawk: Easiest just to call `ToList()` at the end, in that case. :)

Comment: Updated to include the ToList() call.  I wasn't sure if you could bind to the IEnumerable directly or not.  I guess now we know.